# Javascript Array is displayed with unwanted comma

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need your help:
In Javascript I create an array with push.

```
for (const elem of prod[i].motor) {
    if (usedMotor.includes(elem) === false) {
       motor.push('<li>'+elem+'</li>');
       usedMotor.push(elem);
    }
}
```

But if I want to display it with `document.getElementById('spanMotorType').innerHTML = 'Applicable Motors:'+ motor;`
it is printed with comma between the elements.

```
Applicable Motors:
Induction motor
,
Permanent magnet motor
,
Synchronous reluctance motor
```

Console shows this:

```
Array(3) [ "<li>Induction motor</li>", "<li>Permanent magnet motor</li>", 
"<li>Synchronous reluctance motor</li>" ]
0: "<li>Induction motor</li>"
1: "<li>Permanent magnet motor</li>"
2: "<li>Synchronous reluctance motor</li>"
```

Is there a way how I can remove this comma? The length of the Array can be between 1 and 3.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Write it as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('spanMotorType').innerHTML = 'Applicable Motors:'+ motor.join(' ');
```

#### Explanation:

By default, when a string is joined with an Array, the output will print the array items with a comma, because it converts it, as-is, to string, and since there's a comma between Array items, it will also be printed:

```js
document.write(  "foo " + ['a','b','c']  )
```

Without commas:

```js
document.write(  "foo " + ['a','b','c'].join(' ')  )
```

Array [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) converts an Array to a string with your choice of delimiter and not the default comma.

Comment: thank you! It looks so easy and i tried so long with replace, splice and all that. Join works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Setting Array as the `innerHTML` will bind the element with comma. Because Array inclueds that comma when its converted to string.

You have to make the array as a single sting and set the `innerHTML` to get rid of the comma.

Joing the array using `Array.join`, I used empty sting as the joiner. Set the `innerHTML` with this joined string.

```js
const testArr = [1, 2, 3];
const myarray = testArr.map((node) => '<li>' + node + '</li>')
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = myarray.join('');
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

So in your case it should be

```
document.getElementById('spanMotorType').innerHTML = 'Applicable Motors:'+ motor.join('');
```

Please Note

You have to mention some string with which the array is to be joined, or else `,` will be treated as default joiner.

Comment: I can't vote yet, so thank you too for your helpful reply!

Answer (score 1):

Use following code.

```
usermotor.join(" ")
```

https://sebhastian.com/javascript-array-string/